# Possible to cast CGVector to CGPoint since they're of the same size?

Tags: objective-c, c, casting, struct

This works with pointers:

```
CGVector* v = {1, 2};
CGPoint* p = (CGPoint*)v;
```

Here they aren't pointers, so this won't work but this is the typical case:

```
CGVector v = {1, 2};
CGPoint p = (CGPoint)v;
```

Yet I'm wondering, since both structs are of the same size (2x CGFloat) is there any way I can just "cast" the CGVector to CGPoint, ie using the vector as a CGPoint parameter without having to copy & assign the struct fields?

Comment: This should work: `CGPoint p = *((CGPoint*)&v);`

Comment: I've never heard of (and can't find any reference to) CGVector. Do you have a link to any documentation please?

Comment: @JamesWebster It's an iOS 7 structure, defined in [CGGeometry](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000955-CH2g-SW2). If you log into http://developer.apple.com and go to the iOS 7 pre-release developer library, you'll see it there.

Comment: That would explain why I can't find links to documentation (yet)

Comment: <Insert standard iOS NDA grump here>

Comment: While you can use dasblinkenlight's pointer deference technique, I'd be inclined to define a function (e.g. a `CG_INLINE` function like `CGPointMake`) or macro to do the conversion, grabbing the individual elements of the `struct` to convert from one to the other.

Comment: Upps, I wasn't aware that CGVector is new in iOS 7. Spoiled it. Sue me. :)

Comment: Gee, now there's no point in seeing the movie.

Comment: You mean "CGVector{0, 1}"? I think the layman's term for the movie was "Up". ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dasblinkenlight's code `CGPoint p = *((CGPoint*)&v);` will work, assuming the two data-structures have the same memory layout/padding etc.

However, realize this code will still be copying memory into a new variable so it won't be that much faster than just doing things the safe way (member-by-member copy). Either way, use Instruments before deciding on these kinds of hacky optimizations.

You should at least make a macro or function to convert between the types. If you want to do this hack, do it in the macro/function so you can later change it without affecting too much code.

Comment: Doesn't this violate the strict aliasing rule?

Comment: Darn, I was so close, didn't think of the enclosing *(..). Good that you pointed out the memcopy thing. But I was hoping I could just use the type without having to do any conversion at all, if I use a macro I could as well use CGPointMake within the macro.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the memory copy occurs? I imagine that the compiler is clever enough to know that this cast is essentially a pass-by-value situation and then performs the copy automatically, lest the vector leaving scope before the point would make the point's values garbage. Right?